# PyCharm stops at a breakpoint where it shouldn't

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, breakpoints

I'm experiencing this behavior in PyCharm `Build #PY-222.4345.23` on macOS Monterey `12.6.1`, which happens in both python `3.10` and `3.11`.

```
def example(i):
    match i % 4:
        case 0:
            if i > 10:
                return 0
        case 1:
            if i > 10:
                return 1
        case 2:
            if i > 10:
                print(f'{i}, {i > 10}')
                return 2
        case 3:
            if i > 10:
                return 3


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(example(2))
```

In both python versions, debugger stops at 3rd return statement (unexpected, block should be unreachable) but doesn't actually return anything which is the expected behavior for the given input `2`

python 3.11 (1 breakpoint to reproduce)

[image]

python 3.10 (2 breakpoints to reproduce)

[image]

If switch and cases were replaced with `if`/`elif` blocks, the very same breakpoint is never reached which is exactly the behavior I'm expecting for the switch blocks.

```
def example(i):
    j = i % 4
    if j == 0:
        if i > 10:
            return 0
    elif j == 1:
        if i > 10:
            return 1
    elif j == 2:
        if i > 10:
            print(f'{i}, {i > 10}')
            return 2
    elif j == 3:
        if i > 10:
            return 3


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(example(2))
```

Comment: I do not understand what do you expect. Break point just pause execution before that line, so before `return 2`. If you continue (e.g. line by line), the debugger will execute the `return` and so you will have the `2`. But on your code, `return 2` should never be executed. You call `return 2` only if `i > 10`, but you have `i = 2`, so no return. Please specify better what do you expect and what you get.

Comment: Breakpoint should be unreachable hence it should never stop for `i = 2`.

Comment: I've tried this on exactly the same PyCharm build (Community Edition), Python 3.10, but Windows 10 and I can't reproduce the reported behaviour. I only get the breakpoint hit for `example(14)` and not for `example(2)`

Comment: How many breakpoints did you use? If not 2, try placing a second as demonstrated in the screenshot above.

Comment: Ok, yes, I see. I needed both breakpoints set to reproduce. It hits the second breakpoint now.

Answer (score 2):

IDE bug. I've filed a ticket in PyCharm's issue tracker - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-57125/PyCharm-stops-on-non-hit-breakpoint-inside-pattern-matching-block

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already filed a [ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-57074/Debugger-stops-at-a-breakpoint-where-it-shouldnt) with the issue.

Comment: OK, I closed mine as a duplicate and updated yours.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was running the Python application using `uvicorn`. So a quick fix for me was to put the `reload` value to `False`

```
uvicorn.run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8007, reload=False)
```

Also, If you're using `uvicorn` via a shell, remove the `--reload` parameter.

This is hopefully a temporary fix until they fix the issue with Pycharm and Python `3.10+`